# Повторное выполнение кода java

Tags: java

Есть код отправки запроса на сервер в результате которого приходит result с числом (1 или 0). Как выполнить повторный запрос в случае если приходит 1?

```
public class JSON extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        while (true) {
            startLoop();
            try {

                URL url = new URL("site");
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }
                return buffer.toString();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                try {
                    if (reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (result.contains("1")) {

             new JSONTask().execute(a);
            //startTell();

        } else {

        }


    }
```

Comment: Уточни вопрос. Какую библиотеку используешь для выполнения запросов? или какой метод выполняет запрос?

Comment: В вашем случае, перезапускайте свой `AsyncTask` и все.